# Redirect entire site using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do I redirect an entire website and all of its pages/urls to a new site using htaccess?

When I tried the below, it only redirected the home page of the old site to the new site.

`Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com`

When I tried the below, the home page was redirected, but the other pages (`www.oldsite.com/register`) on the old site got 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.newsite\.com\" [R=301,L]
```

Ex:

www.oldsite.com --> www.newsite.com

www.oldsite.com/register --> www.newsite.com

www.oldsite.com/images/cats --> www.newsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i understand you need to redirect every thing in old domain to just index page in new domain , so The following code should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```